# Difference between ls -l and du

Tags: macos, unix, operating-system

I hava a file naming `xyx.txt` and `ls -l` shows as below:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 MRG  staff  8000000 Jul  7 01:30 xyz.txt
```

But when i fire `du xyz.txt` then below is the output:

```
15632   xyz.txt
```

Can somebody please tell me why is the difference and what's the real size of the file in disk. Thanks.

> **N.B.**: `OS info`:  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5

Comment: du is telling you the number of "blocks" the file takes up on disk -- often 512 bytes per block. ls is telling you the logical file size; du is talking about how much hardware is being used to store the file, and its number is sometimes a little higher. Do the math, you'll see it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/du/):

> The `du` utility displays the file system block usage for each file argument
>
> [...]
>
> If `BLOCKSIZE` is not set, and the `-k`
>                   option is not specified, the block counts will be displayed in
>                   512-byte blocks.

Answer (score 2):

UNIX file systems allow for sparse files.  The unallocated blocks read as 0, but take up no space on disk.  The `du` command will give the actual number of allocated blocks, while `ls` will show you the total size of the allocated blocks and unallocated holes.

That said, that's not what is happening here.

`du` is showing you the total number of 512-byte blocks (15632) that the file occupies.  `ls` is showing you the actual file size (8,000,000 bytes).  512 * 15632 = 8003584, which is 8,000,000 rounded up to the next 4K byte boundary.

This file isn't sparse, and both numbers are in agreement.